# Difference between { zip map } and { flatMap map } in Future of Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency

I'm reading 《hands on scala》, and one of its exercise is parallelizing merge sort.

I want to know why for-comprehension, which can be translated into flatMap and map, takes more time than zip and map.

my code:

```
def mergeSortParallel0[T: Ordering](items: IndexedSeq[T]): Future[IndexedSeq[T]] = {
    if (items.length <= 16) Future.successful(mergeSortSequential(items))
    else {
        val (left, right) = items.splitAt(items.length / 2)
        for (
          l <- mergeSortParallel0(left);
          r <- mergeSortParallel0(right)
        ) yield merge(l, r)
    }
}
```

the standard answer provided by book:

```
def mergeSortParallel0[T: Ordering](items: IndexedSeq[T]): Future[IndexedSeq[T]] = {
    if (items.length <= 16) Future.successful(mergeSortSequential(items))
    else {
        val (left, right) = items.splitAt(items.length / 2)
        mergeSortParallel0(left).zip(mergeSortParallel0(right)).map{
            case (sortedLeft, sortedRight) => merge(sortedLeft, sortedRight)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`flatMap` or `map` are sequential operations on Scala Future and on their own have nothing to do with running things in parallel. They can be viewed as simple callbacks executed when a Future completes. Or in other words, provided code inside `map(...)` or `flatMap(...)` will start to execute only when the previous Future is finished.

`zip` on the other hand will run your Futures in parallel and return the result as a Tuple when both of them are complete. Similarly, you could use `zipWith` which takes a function to transform the results of two Futures (combines zip and map operations):

```
      mergeSortParallel0(left).zipWith(mergeSortParallel0(right)){
        case (sortedLeft, sortedRight) => merge(sortedLeft, sortedRight)
      }
```

Another way to achieve parallelism is to declare Futures outside for-comprehension. This works as Futures in Scala are 'eager' and they start as soon as you declare them (assign to `val`):

```
  def mergeSortParallel0[T: Ordering](items: IndexedSeq[T]): Future[IndexedSeq[T]] = {
    if (items.length <= 16) Future.successful(mergeSortSequential(items))
    else {
      val (left, right) = items.splitAt(items.length / 2)
      val leftF = mergeSortParallel0(left)
      val rightF = mergeSortParallel0(right)

      for {
        sortedLeft <- leftF
        sortedRight <- rightF
      } yield {
        merge(sortedLeft, sortedRight)
      }
    }
  }
```